# Combining two methods in one

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, math, methods

I currently have 2 methods. The first method says what is the row with the highest average and the second one says what is the column with the highest average. I want to merge these two methods into one but I don't know how. the parameter is an array of doubles and the return type should be a string that says for the rows (R3 for example) and for the columns (C3)

What I tried to do is create 4 for-loops (2 for loops for the rows and 2 for loops for the columns) but when I try to return the highest average of the column it will say "unreachable statement" because I can't use return twice. Any suggestions?

the code below is the two methods I have right now. what the methods are doing is getting the averages of each row/column and then compare them.

```
public static double findHighestRow(double[][] grid) {
        int i, j;
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double averageGreater = 0;
        
        for (i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                sum = sum + grid[i][j];
            }
            average=sum/grid[i].length;
            sum=0;
            averageGreater = Math.max(average, sum / grid[i].length);
            System.out.println("Average of row " + (i+1) + " = " + average);
        }

        System.out.println(" row with highest average is " + (i) + " = " + averageGreater);
        return averageGreater;
    }
    
    public static double findHighestColumn(double grid[][]) {
        int k, l;
        double sum2 = 0;
        double average2 = 0;
        double averageGreater2 = 0;
        
        for (k = 0; k < grid.length; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < grid[k].length; l++) {
                sum2=sum2+grid[k][l];
            }
            average2=sum2/grid[k].length;
            sum2 = 0;
            averageGreater2 = Math.max(average2, sum2 / grid[k].length);
            System.out.println("Average of column " + (k+1) + " = " + average2);
        }
        
        System.out.println(" column with highest average is " + (k) + " = " + averageGreater2);
        return averageGreater2;
    }
```

This is the code that is failing. Another problem is that I do not know how to convert the result into a string.

```
public static double findHighestRow(double[][] grid) {
        int i, j;
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double averageGreater = 0;
        
        for (i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                sum = sum + grid[i][j];
            }
            average=sum/grid[i].length;
            sum=0;
            averageGreater = Math.max(average, sum / grid[i].length);
            System.out.println("Average of row " + (i+1) + " = " + average);
        }
        
        System.out.println(" row with highest average is " + (i) + " = " + averageGreater);
        return averageGreater;
        
        int k, l;
        double sum2 = 0;
        double average2 = 0;
        double averageGreater2 = 0;
        
        for (k = 0; k < grid.length; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < grid[k].length; l++) {
                sum2=sum2+grid[k][l];
            }
            average2=sum2/grid[k].length;
            sum2 = 0;
            averageGreater2 = Math.max(average2, sum2 / grid[k].length);
            System.out.println("Average of column " + (k+1) + " = " + average2);
        }
        
        System.out.println(" column with highest average is " + (k) + " = " + averageGreater2);
        return averageGreater2;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem with two results but you can try to create a class, for example Result with fields highestRow and highestColumn and then return an instance of that class.

Comment: You haven't shown the code that's failing. You stated that you're going to return a string with the information but none of these methods do that.

Comment: I edited your question and removed all unnecessary white spaces to make it more readable and noticed you are missing a `}` after a `return` statement. You may want to edit your question so what we can see the correct code (unless this is the problem you are having).

Comment: Could you provide more information on what the resulting `String` should look like? I suggest you edit the question to show an input example and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine the contents of two methods that return values the way you did. Not properly scoping your "return" statements will result in a compilation error.

```
public static double findHighestRow(double[][] grid) {
        int i, j;
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double averageGreater = 0;
        
        for (i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                sum = sum + grid[i][j];
            }
            average=sum/grid[i].length;
            sum=0;
            averageGreater = Math.max(average, sum / grid[i].length);
            System.out.println("Average of row " + (i+1) + " = " + average);
        }
        
        System.out.println(" row with highest average is " + (i) + " = " + averageGreater);
        return averageGreater;
        
        int k, l; // this is unreachable code because of the return statement that preceded it.
```

You will need to properly scope those return statements. One possible way is by enclosing it in an `if` statement.

The important thing is to clearly outline your logic so you will know when to return a value, and how to return it. Pseudocode often helps beginner developers to figure this out. You can have something like this (pseudocode)

```
WHEN HIGHEST ROW FOUND
THEN FIND HIGHEST COLUMN
LASTLY RETURN ROW AND COL
```

Which implies that the logic will calculate one portion first, and then when that process is done, will calculate the other. Lastly, will return the value needed.

Also, if you are combining these two methods, the implication is that your method cannot return a single value anymore. Instead, it need to return a tuple (`[row, col]`). Since Java does not have `Tuple` as a data type, you will have to create your own. You can use an array, or you can use a class that represent a tuple. An easy way to do this is by using a Java record.

```
public record Tuple(int row, int col){}
```

If using this approach, your code will have to be modified something like this:

```
public static Tuple findHighestRow(double[][] grid) {
        int i, j;
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double averageGreater = 0;
        
        for (i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                sum = sum + grid[i][j];
            }
            average=sum/grid[i].length;
            sum=0;
            averageGreater = Math.max(average, sum / grid[i].length);
            System.out.println("Average of row " + (i+1) + " = " + average);
        }
        
        System.out.println(" row with highest average is " + (i) + " = " + averageGreater);
        
        int k, l;
        double sum2 = 0;
        double average2 = 0;
        double averageGreater2 = 0;
        
        for (k = 0; k < grid.length; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < grid[k].length; l++) {
                sum2=sum2+grid[k][l];
            }
            average2=sum2/grid[k].length;
            sum2 = 0;
            averageGreater2 = Math.max(average2, sum2 / grid[k].length);
            System.out.println("Average of column " + (k+1) + " = " + average2);
        }
        
        System.out.println(" column with highest average is " + (k) + " = " + averageGreater2);
        return new Tuple(i, k);
    }
```

I'm also convinced there is a better algorithm to find these rows and columns. This looks like a brute force solution to me. That said, I just wanted to focus on your immediate issue. I am no algorithm expert, but I think if you create a POJO that captures a tuple of `[row, col]` and the value in a list or array, you can then much easier return the max value in your list rather than iterate again through the same 2D array twice. For example:

```
3, 2, 1
4, 5, 9
7, 8, 6
```

Given a 2D array like the one above, you can capture the following data after one pass in a list of `MyPojo` objects

```
MyPojo: [0,0], 3
MyPojo: [1,2], 9
MyPojo: [2,1], 8
```

Then all you have to do is provide a method in `MyPojo` that returns the tuple of the highest value. For this, you will need to create a `Comparator`. You can use a lambda expression for this.

```
MyPojo maxValue = myList
      .stream()
      .max(Comparator.comparing(MyPojo::value))
```

The getter method name `value` is correct, if using a Java Record. Records don't append `get` or `set` to the getters and setters. If using a plain class, it would be whatever the method name of that getter function. Once you have the object, you can either return the `[row, col]` or the value.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the question, I suspect the O/P wants the *result* of two methods combined into one. But, first, the unreachable statement:

### Part 1: Unreachable Statement

Consider the first part of your code, which has this in the middle:

```
 ... 
 System.out.println(" row with highest average is " + (i) 
                  + " = " + averageGreater);
 return averageGreater;
 ...
```

Execution of that `return` statement is unavoidable: It  is not subject to an `if` or other conditional flow control.

Execution of a `return` statement terminates execution of the method that contains it. Because reaching that `return` is unavoidable, the code below it cannot be executed. That causes the "unreachable statement" error.

### Part 2: How to convert the result into a string.

You say you "do not know how to convert the result into a string."

You actually *do* know how to do that. You've done it in your code.

Consider, for example,  this statement, from your code:

```
 System.out.println(" row with highest average is " + (i) 
                        + " = " + averageGreater);
```

`System.out` is an instance of a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). The overloaded `println` method you are using is taking a `String` argument. That's a **single** `String`, not four `String`.

So, how does that work?  Although `String` is a class, the Java compiler provides special support for it, which includes overloading `+` to act as a `String` concatenation operator. When used on a primitive, the `+` is overloaded to convert the primitive to a `String`. For `Object`s, it acts as if the `toString` method was called.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String foo = "foo";
    String bar = "bar";       
    int bin = 3;
    String foobar = foo + bar + bin;
    System.out.println (foobar);        
}
```

Output: `foobar3`

So, a potential solution to your problem might be this:

Change

```
 public static double findHighestRow(double[][] grid) {
```

to

```
 public static String findHighestRow (double[][] grid) {
```

which ends thus:

```
    return (" row with highest average is " + (i) + " = " + averageGreater);
 }
```

Make similar changes to your `public static double findHighestColumn(double grid[][])`  .

If desired, both methods and the results they return can be combined in one statement, similar to this:

```
 String result = findHighestRow (theGrid) + findHighestColumn (theGrid);
```